# SVG Element Click In React After Loading From a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I would like to load an SVG using a dynamically generated URL (depending on React props) and then assign "click" event handlers to various regions within the SVG.

The SVGs will be coded with clickable regions with a special class say, "click-region". These SVGs will then be uploaded to a publicly accessible URL from where they will be loaded depending upon the client.

The idea is that once the SVG is loaded, I would fire a jQuery "on" method for a click event handler.

```
$('.click-region').on('click', { data: someData }, this.handleClickRegion);
```

The above code works fine if I paste the SVG inline. If I load it from a URL, then the jQuery handler doesn't work as expected.

I'm guessing that the jQuery tries to wire things up before the SVG is loaded.

Any help would be great.

Alternatively, I would love to know if there's a better way to handle such SVG in a React app if we don't know the structure/configuration beforehand. Is there a way to do this in React w/o jQuery?

Comment: Why aren't you connecting the handler at the point that you "load it from a URL"?

Comment: Hello, I seem to have figured this out using the same approach you mentioned. I am using a Promise to load the SVG, and once the SVG is loaded, I am wiring up a CLICK handler. The issue now is that when I click the element, I would like to update the React State, but it doesn't happen. Investigating if this is the right strategy or not. Thanks!